# How to parse "5/17/2018 12:00:00 PM" string to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have tried to "5/17/2018 12:00:00 PM" with DateTime.Parse and DateTime.ParseExact and some formats made by me but unfortunately, each test resulted in: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
This is the last thing that I tried.

```
public DateTime Convert_date(string date)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();

        string format ="M/d/yyyy h/mm/ss tt";

        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out dt))
        {
            return dt;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("The string couldn't be converted to date time!");
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: `var date = DateTime.Parse("5/17/2018 12:00:00 PM");` works fine for me. Also, your custom format string has the `'/'` character between the hours, minutes and seconds, while the actual sample string has the `':'` character.

Comment: Thanks, the lack of sleep makes its presence felt, I don't know how I missed it. Now it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In string format you have `/` for time. Try this

```
string format ="M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: It's working now, thanks :D I don't know how I missed it...

Comment: @AlexandruGazdac I hate such typos they are hard to spot :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime Convert_date(string date)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();

    string format ="M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";

    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out dt))
    {
        return dt;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("The string couldn't be converted to date time!");
    return dt;
}
```

Kindly give it a try, since M/d/yyyy h/mm/ss tt is not valid format. Hope this helps.